# What does dot mean in bin.includes in build.properties in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have the following `build.properties` in my sample application:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .
```

File was generated by IDE.

What does dot at the end mean?

If it means to process all files in the current directory, then what for `plugin.xml` file mentioned there? Since it is in the current directory it would be processed implicitly by dot.

If it means to process all subdirectories in the current directory, then what for `META-INF` directory mentioned there? Since it is in the current directory it would be processed implicitly by dot.

If non above is correct, then what does dot mean actually? If I set there some `myfile.bin`, what will happen then?

Answer (score 4):

It means the folder configured by the `output..` line - this line is a bit confusing, it is `output.` followed by a folder, in this case `.`.  This is the same as the default output folder configured in the `Java Build Path`.

So `.` actually mean the contents of the `bin` folder.

Comment: And what is `plugin.xml` then? I see no such file inside `bin`. Why does `dot` written relative to `bin`, while `plugin.xml` written relative to... what?

Comment: `.` is not a file inside `bin` it means the `bin` folder - where you see `.` in the includes substitute `bin`. So that means everything is relative to the project root.